# Is it possible to bring electronics as gift from US to Bangladesh?

Tags: usa, electronic-items, bangladesh

I will be visiting US in few days. And my nephew wants me to get a GTX 970 for him from there (these are overpriced in my country).

Is it possible to bring it from US when I come back to Bangladesh? Will it be blocked by the customs?

Comment: This depends entirely on where you are returning to from the US.

Comment: If it is sold in your country, there should be no issues bringing it in.  BUT you could be charged duty on the item, which may bring it right back up to the selling price at home.

Comment: Where are you returning to? Each country is different.

Comment: I'll be returning to Bangladesh.

Comment: According to Chapter 85 Bangladesh Customs Tariff rules www.nbr-bd.org/nbrweb/TariffPdfs/ch85n.pdf it _looks_ like a 10% duty for a video card. However, you won't know the exact amount until you attempt to enter the country with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you are trying to enter the country with something prohibited or illegal, customs will not "block" it. They will, however, charge you import duties on anything you are importing--gifts included.  Most (all?) countries provide an exception up to a certain value and for certain items, meaning you may not have to pay duties on gifts if they are cheap enough.

According to [this PDF](http://www.nbr-bd.org/nbrweb/TariffPdfs/ch85n.pdf) from Bangladesh customs (t/h @GCCampbell), you will be charged a 10% import duty for your graphics card.  So be sure to carry the receipt with you to prove how much you paid. Otherwise the customs officer will be forced to estimate the value, and his estimate may not be favorable to you!

Comment: Also, Bangladesh does not have an exemption based on value of goods imported.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, drop the packaging, and carry it in the the cabin-luggage/side-bag. You are out-of-trouble.

In very rare case, even if you questioned, say it is for personal usage. You are good to go.

Comment: Are you suggesting lying to customs officers with the purpose of smuggling electronics?

Comment: @JoErNanO in context of Bangladesh, it is a case of "you are thinking too much". i can't talk much about around the world. But, in context of Bangladesh, "smuggling" means bringing something legal in bulk, e.g. more than 5 piece of same stuff; and, bringing in something illegal e.g. narcotics, weapons etc. in any amount. And, yes, bringing in lot of electronic gifts is a very common scenario in Bangladesh airports.

Comment: @kmonsoor: If what you propose is not illegal in Bangladesh, then why are you proposing lying to customs about it?

Comment: @HenningMakholm i don't know how much you know/experienced about corruption/bad-policies in southeast asia, it may sound strange, pure-honesty is what pretty much translates to asking for trouble. Even clear good intentions can easily make the water muddy here. Sounds bad? I know. How it can be real? it's real pretty much like Trump.

Comment: @kmonsoor: _By definition_, if the authorities knowing the truth about what you're carrying will get you into trouble, then what you're carrying is **NOT OK**.

Comment: @HenningMakholm this world don't runs "By definition". My answer is in context with OP's question about a graphics card. Nothing else. Anyway, i won't continue pushing my arrogant opinion. Let's mutually agree to disagree.